# COLLATION is not valid for CHARACTER SET not corresponding to my settings

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, collation

I have asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20643255/1801588) for my problem with collation setting, which seems to be ignored/overriden by some unwanted defaults. To workaround this, I want to use `COLLATE` in the queries returning "[illegal mix of collations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3029321/1801588)" error. However, when I try to, I get "COLLATION is not valid" error instead.

The query in question (I didn't face this problem with other queries yet), this time with `COLLATE` on the parameter (`?` translates to a string of comma-separated numbers):

```
SELECT k.url 
FROM kml k 
WHERE (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        kat.kategorie ORDER BY kat.kategorie 
    )
    FROM kml_kategorie kat
    WHERE kat.kml = k.id
) = ? COLLATE utf8_czech_ci
LIMIT 1;
```

When running it, I get following error:

```
COLLATION 'utf8_czech_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
```

When I run `show variables like "%character_set_%"` in Adminer, I get following results:

```
---------------------------------------  
| Variable_name            | Value    |  
---------------------------------------  
| character_set_client     | utf8     |  
| character_set_connection | utf8     |  
| character_set_database   | utf8     |  
| character_set_filesystem | binary   |  
| character_set_results    | utf8     |  
| character_set_server     | utf8     |  
| character_set_system     | utf8     |  
---------------------------------------
```

When I invoke the command from php/mysqli, the only difference is that even `character_set_filesystem` has value of `utf8`.

Well, perhaps in this case the database settings are used no matter what is shown to the mysqli. But then I tried to solve any coercibility issues by adding `COLLATE` to the aggregate function, `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT k.url 
FROM kml k 
WHERE (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        kat.kategorie ORDER BY kat.kategorie COLLATE utf8_czech_ci 
    )
    FROM kml_kategorie kat
    WHERE kat.kml = k.id
) = ?
LIMIT 1;
```

Now the error is following:

```
COLLATION 'utf8_czech_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

You can see that there is no `latin1` among the charset variable values. It used to be the value of `character_set_server` before I modified `my.cnf` file. Its relevant part now looks like this:

```
## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
collation_server=utf8_czech_ci
character_set_server=utf8
character-set-filesystem=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
```

Where do the charsets shown in the error messages (and causing the problem) come from? I'm bit confused by the differences between querying the variables from mysqli/php and adminer, and *totally* confused by some other variables making this even bigger mess. How to clean it and change the variables so that at least this this COLLATE workaround worked?

This is basically a subquestion to [my linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20643255/1801588), but different enough to merit splitting; the two questions combined would be as messy as my database variables. However, it's quite probable that the solution to one of them will make the other solved as well; after answering, you might consider answering the other question by a summary of your first answer + a note how it applies to the problem specified in the question.

EDIT: I found [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28893929/1801588) for this one particular case. However, I still didn't find **why the queries made through Adminer and Mysqli returned different results** and **especially why the error message points to charsets not included in any variable**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the datatype of kat.kategorie ?

```
GROUP_CONCAT( kat.kategorie
              ORDER BY CONVERT(kat.kategorie USING utf8) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci 
            )
```

You may also need a call to `CAST(... AS CHAR)`.

In the future, do not mix CHARACTER SETs.

`GROUP_CONCAT`, and a couple of other functions that involve combining things, have a problem in deducing what the result type should be. In some cases, it punts and calls the result `BINARY`, which is even worse than what you encountered.

I believe that there is a latin1 somewhere that led to your particular problem. Dig into Adminer. Let's see SHOW CREATE TABLE kat.

Comment: "In the future, do not mix CHARACTER SETs" - my point is how to correct mixed CHARACTER SETs when they don't correspond my variables; see the last edit of my question. Your answer is just another workaround, not as good as mine for this particular situation, but with more general usage. It's a fish, but now I need to learn fishing (making charsets the same across whole system) more.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT`, and a couple of other functions that involve combining things, have a problem in deducing what the result is.  In some cases, it punts and calls the result `BINARY`, which leads is even worse than what you encountered.  I believe that there is a `latin1` somewhere that led to your particular problem.  Dig into Adminer.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE kat`.

Comment: your comment explains a lot. Add it to your question and I'll upvote and probably accept it on Monday (I don't have time to consider it thoroughly earlier).

Comment: After another look at the problem I found its core: kat.kategorie is integer. Mysqli can convert it to char/varchar, but there's no character set and collation stored for the integer column. Playing with defaults to set the correct charset and collation led to a dead end, so I consider your answer a proper solution now. Accepted.

Comment: Based on another thread, it may be that the character set of a number may come from `@@character_set_filesystem` (or _server).  The solution there was "don't collate numbers".

Comment: Adminer is getting in the way?  <cynical>That's what is irritating about 3rd party software.</cynical>

Answer (score 0):

I made another workaround: I created a view in my database to avoid calling `GROUP_CONCAT` in the mysqli parametrized query. The error no longer appears, but **I still don't consider it fully resolved, because there are some strange things I don't understand** (variables not correctly set etc.) and I don't want them to make any more problems.

The view:

```
CREATE 
  ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
  SQL 
  SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `kml_kat_vw` AS SELECT 
  `kml_kategorie`.`kml` AS `_kml`,
  group_concat(
    `kml_kategorie`.`kategorie`
    ORDER BY `kml_kategorie`.`kategorie` ASC separator ','
  ) AS `_kategorie` 
FROM `kml_kategorie`
GROUP BY `kml_kategorie`.`kml`
```

The new query:

```
SELECT k.url
FROM kml k
JOIN kml_kat_vw kat ON kat._kml = k.id
WHERE kat._kategorie = ?;
```