# Insert data in Hindi in database using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table structure like this.

[image]

I want to insert values in `examples` column that can be either in Hindi or English. To insert values, I have added a procedure as follows:

```
 PROCEDURE `insertCategories`(parentCatID INT(11), categoryName VARCHAR(100), categoryType VARCHAR(100), examples VARCHAR(200))
 BEGIN
  DECLARE parentID INT(11) DEFAULT parentCatID; 
  DECLARE categoryTitle VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT categoryName;
  DECLARE catType VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT categoryType;
  DECLARE catExamples VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT examples;
  IF categoryTitle !='' AND catType!=''  THEN
    INSERT INTO categories(cat_title, parent_catID, `types`, examples) VALUE(categoryTitle, parentID, catType, catExamples);
  END IF;
END$$
```

I am trying to call this procedure using `$executingProcedure = $mysqli->query("CALL insertCategories(0, 'Exporter', 'BC', 'निर्यातक')");`

But it stores value like

```
 &#2344;&#2367;&#2352;&#2381;&#2351;&#2366;&#2340;&#2325;
```

I know this is charset problem which I tried to fix with the solution given on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13101526/4932070), but it didn't work. I am stuck at this problem and any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have tried it in `mysql` and it's working, but I need to do this using `mysqli`.

**EDIT**

Seems like problem was in html part. Added the following tag and everything worked fine.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Why are you using a sproc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store the data in unicode in hindi language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435867/how-to-store-the-data-in-unicode-in-hindi-language)

Comment: @ManojSalvi I have already tried that and searched the websites, but not worked for me.

Comment: @Strawberry requirement of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add set charset to utf-8.

In short you need to add following line anywhere in `<head>` in both pages from you saving and where you showing. It will work doesn't matter, you saving `mysqli` or `mysql`.

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

It will work.

Comment: Brother, In your database, Is the Collation is set to utf8_bin? 
latin1_swedish_ci should also work.

Comment: Adding your code didn't work. I have added a tag mentioned in the edit and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use `utf8_general_ci` collation for `example` column in your table structure.
And use following PHP statement in your PHP script.

```
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```